# Getting incompatible AVD error while running instrumentation test ion Gitlab CI

Tags: android, testing, gitlab, instrumentation, gitlab-ci

I am getting below error whenever I am trying to run instrumentation test for my android project:

```
Skipping device 'test(AVD)' for 'app:': Unknown API Level

 > : No compatible devices connected.[TestRunner] FAILED 
Found 1 connected device(s), 0 of which were compatible.
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///builds/antitheft/anti-theft-screen-lock/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 45.163 secs
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I am using shared runner. My target API is 25 and I am trying to run the AVD on API 22.

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT: "5"
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "25"
  ANDROID_TEST_SDK: "22"
  ANDROID_ABI: "armeabi-v7a"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "25.0.2"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "24.4.1"
  IS_CI_BUILD : "true"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.tgz https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.tgz
  - tar --extract --gzip --file=android-sdk.tgz
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_TEST_SDK}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build   #Generates the release and debug build
  - test    #Performs unit and insttrumentation tests.

debugBuild:   #Generate debug build for dev and master branch
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  only:
    - master
    - dev
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/

unitTests:  #Unit tests
  stage: test
  script:
    #Run the unit test
    - ./gradlew test

functionalTests:  #Instrumantation tests
  stage: test
  script:
     #Download the wait for emulator script
    - wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
    - chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator

    #Download emulator image for armeabi-v7a
    - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-${ANDROID_TEST_SDK}

    #Create AVD
    - echo no | android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd --force -n test -t android-${ANDROID_TEST_SDK} --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a

    #Start the AVD and wait for the emulator to start
    - android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-arm -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
    - ./android-wait-for-emulator

    #Display list of devices
    - adb devices

    #Unloack device and run the instrumantation test
    - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
    - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

Help me with resolving this issue. I am trying to run it for last 4-5 days with no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with similar problem too, finally I am success with this config

```
image: gengjiawen/android-ndk

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/

unitTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test

functionalTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - sdkmanager "system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a"
    - echo no | avdmanager create avd --force -n test -k "system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a"
    - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
    - wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/master/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
    - chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
    - ./android-wait-for-emulator
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    - ./gradlew cAT
```